# Ionic tabs directive facebook login

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework

I am attempting to add facebook login to my ionic app.
I am following this tutorial: https://ccoenraets.github.io/ionic-tutorial/ionic-facebook-integration.html

However, it uses the sidemenu directive and therefore I am having trouble following as the codes are not the same.

Is there a tutorial for adding facebook login to the tabs directive?
Thanks!

Comment: What kind of problems are you having with the tabs directive?